# Initializing sub-vectors of nested vectors with reserved capacity

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I want to create vector of vectors such that each sub-vector has a pre-defined capacity but is not initialized.

Here is the code which doesn't do what I want to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> tVec;
    tVec.reserve( 5 );
    cout<<"tVec Size: "<<tVec.size()<<", capacity: "<<tVec.capacity()<<endl;

    vector< vector<int> > tmpVecVec( 2, tVec );
    cout<<"tmpVecVec[0] Size: "<<tmpVecVec[0].size()<<", capacity: "<<tmpVecVec[0].capacity()<<endl;
    cout<<"tmpVecVec[1] Size: "<<tmpVecVec[1].size()<<", capacity: "<<tmpVecVec[0].capacity()<<endl;
}
```

Output of above is:

```
tVec Size: 0, capacity: 5
tmpVecVec[0] Size: 0, capacity: 0
tmpVecVec[1] Size: 0, capacity: 0
```

I want to know how can I get the following result

```
tVec Size: 0, capacity: 5
tmpVecVec[0] Size: 0, capacity: 5
tmpVecVec[1] Size: 0, capacity: 5
```

Of course if I replace reserve with resize or provide size 5 in constructor of tVec, I can do this. But, can I do this without using these methods ?

link to working code: http://ideone.com/PBXeP

Comment: I don't think you can. For better or worse, `vector` doesn't have a constructor that allows you to request an initial capacity.

Comment: So as I understand, it cant be done with STL. Can it be done using Boost  or some other method ?

Comment: @nurav, there's little that Boost can do to help you with `vector` in this case. I don't understand why you would place such requirements on this algorithm, considering it's only a line or two to reserve the capacity in all your vectors.

Comment: Actually why I want to do this so that I can fill sub-vectors with push-back. Consider vector of vector with million sub-vectors. If each sub-vector has a pre-allocated but uninitialized memory of x locations, then i can fill each sub-vector using push_back without causing re-allocations/re-copy as long as number of elements pushed per sub-vector is less than the reserved capacity x.

Comment: @nurav, I don't think that part of your requirement is odd; I (maybe mis-)interpreted that you didn't want to reserve each sub-vector separately, which is how I think you *should* tackle this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you should use if you want the described behaviour with `vector`s. (It may not satisfy all the later requirements you placed.)

```
int size = 5, capacity = 5;
vector<vector<int>> tmpVecVec(size);
for (auto& vec: tmpVecVec)
   vec.reserve(capacity);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    vector<vector<int>>baz(5);
    baz.reserve(5);
    baz[0].reserve(10);
    baz[0].reserve(20);

    printf(" %i ",baz.capacity());
    printf(" %i ",baz[0].capacity());
    printf(" %i ",baz[1].capacity());
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

output is 5, 10 and 20

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is defined by your library's implementation, so it's not great, but it will likely work for small element counts:

```
vector<int>tVec(5, 0);
cout << "tVec Size: " << tVec.size() << ", capacity: " << tVec.capacity() << endl;
vector<vector<int> >tmpVecVec(2, tVec);
tmpVecVec[0].clear();
tmpVecVec[1].clear();
cout << "tmpVecVec[0] Size: " << tmpVecVec[0].size() << ", capacity: " << tmpVecVec[0].capacity() << endl;
cout << "tmpVecVec[1] Size: " << tmpVecVec[1].size() << ", capacity: " << tmpVecVec[0].capacity() << endl;
```

Which output:

```
tmpVecVec[0] Size: 0, capacity: 5
tmpVecVec[1] Size: 0, capacity: 5
```

on my system using GNU's libstdc++ and LLVM's libc++.

but i would assume reserve() is the better approach.